# focus on textbox which are below and not in adjacent using jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I would like to focus on textbox which are below one another.after writing query for enter which acts as tab,the focus is not next textbox which are adjacent to each other.but i want the focus on textbox which are below one another.Here is the query which I used.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('input:text:first').focus();
    var $inp=$('.cls');

    $inp.bind('keydown',function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if(key == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var nxtIdx = $inp.index(this) + 1;
    $(".cls:eq(" + nxtIdx + ")").focus();
    }
    });
    });
```

.cls is the classname used for various textboxes.Kindly help.Thanks inadvance.

Comment: Show the HTML mate and you have syntax error, Try with fixing syntax  `$(".cls").eq(nxtIdx ).focus()`

Comment: But i have multiple textboxes.so how should I write my code.

Comment: Some textboxes are in adjacent position while some are below.so I want the focus should be on the textboxes which are below .

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".input:text:first").keydown(function (e) {

   var key = e.which;
    if(key == 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).next('.cls').focus();
    }
    });

});
```

may this function work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps you. we cannot help you more if we don't have enough HTML info.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:text:first').focus();
    $(".cls").keydown(function (e) {
      if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('.cls').focus();
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<input type='text' class='cls'>
<input type='text' class='cls'>
<input type='text' class='cls'>
<input type='text' class='cls'>
<input type='text' class='cls'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".ele").on("keyup", function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13 || e.keyCode == 13) {
                var ele = $(this);
                var nextAll = ele.nextAll(".ele");
                var next = nextAll.filter(function() {
                    return (ele.offset().top != $(this).offset().top)
                });
                next.eq(0).focus();
                return false;
            }
        });

    });
```

HTML:

```
    <textarea class="ele" placeholder="Sample textarea"></textarea>
    <textarea class="ele" placeholder="Sample textarea"></textarea>
    <textarea class="ele" placeholder="Sample textarea"></textarea>
    <textarea class="ele" placeholder="Sample textarea"></textarea>
    <textarea class="ele" placeholder="Sample textarea"></textarea>
    <textarea class="ele" placeholder="Sample textarea"></textarea>
    <textarea class="ele" placeholder="Sample textarea"></textarea>
    <textarea class="ele" placeholder="Sample textarea"></textarea>
    <textarea class="ele" placeholder="Sample textarea"></textarea>
    <textarea class="ele" placeholder="Sample textarea"></textarea>
    <textarea class="ele" placeholder="Sample textarea"></textarea>
    <textarea class="ele" placeholder="Sample textarea"></textarea>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/86n05y2c/2/

To test it, try resizing the jsfiddle layout.

**Explanation:** As per your requirements, you need to focus on the textboxes which are below the current textboxes ie the top offset of the current and next textboxes should not be same. This is the basic condition for this to work. 
To make it more specific, you can further add a condition of left,right offsets too.